# Laravel query join child table as array

Tags: php, laravel

I have this data

```
$result = DB::table('zone_regions')
    ->where('zone_regions.id', '=', $request->input('zone'))
    ->join('areas', function ($join) use($area) {
        $join->on('zone_regions.id', '=', 'areas.zone_id')
        ->where('areas.id', '=', $area);
    })
    ->join('hthree_regions', function ($join) use($city) {
        $join->on('areas.id', '=', 'hthree_regions.area_id')
        ->where('hthree_regions.id', '=', $city);
    })
    ->join('segments', function ($join) use($segment) {
        $join->on('hthree_regions.id', '=', 'segments.hthree_id')
        ->where('segments.id', '=', $segment);
    })
    ->join('links', function ($join) use($link) {
        $join->on('segments.id', '=', 'links.segment_id')
        ->where('links.id', '=', $link);
    })
    ->join('titik_closurs', function ($join) use($closure) {
        $join->on('links.id', '=', 'titik_closurs.link_id')
        ->where('titik_closurs.id', '=', $closure);
    })
    // ->leftjoin('core_histories', 'titik_closurs.id', '=', 'core_histories.titik_id')
    // ->select('titik_closurs.*', 'core_histories.*')
    ->groupBy('titik_closurs.id')
    ->get();
```

I want to add `titik_closurs` histories (core_histories) as an array into my returned data.

#### Sample data

`Current data`

This is what I have currently

```
data: [{...}]
    0: {...}
        id: 3
        latitude: "6.2088000"
        longitude: "106.8456000"
        site_name: "98987454-54741115"
        user_id: 1
        zone_id: 2
```

And this is what I want to have

```
data: [{...}]
    0: {...}
        id: 3
        latitude: "6.2088000"
        longitude: "106.8456000"
        site_name: "98987454-54741115"
        user_id: 1
        zone_id: 2
        histories: [{......}]
```

`histories: [{......}]` array added to the results.

**Note**

This data (current data) are a bit messed up as is include data of all joined tables in my function, what I really need is just data of table `titik_closurs` and child of it table `core_histories` the rest aren't really useful for me in this case.

**Sample of final data I wish to have:**

```
data: [{...}]
    0: {...}
        // just data of `titik_closurs` exclude data of `zone_regions, areas, hthree_regions` etc.
        id: 3
        latitude: "6.2088000"
        longitude: "106.8456000"
        site_name: "98987454-54741115"
          histories: [{....}]
```

**Any idea how to do that?**

## Update

If I change my query (last part) to something like this:

```
->join('titik_closurs', function ($join) use($closure) {
  $join->on('links.id', '=', 'titik_closurs.link_id')
    ->where('titik_closurs.id', '=', $closure)

    ->leftjoin('core_histories', function ($joinn) {
      $joinn->on('titik_closurs.id', '=', 'core_histories.titik_id');
    });

  })
->groupBy('titik_closurs.id')
->get();
```

It does join `core_histories` to `titik_closurs` BUT,

1. It doesn't show them as child array
2. It only gets first `core_histories` not all.

Comment: You should use an eloquent model and a relationship

Comment: @apokryfos not possible i guess, as you see `titik_closurs` and `core_histories` are like 5 model relationship deeper than my `zone_regions` table which my query began with. Unless you had other point that I misunderstood.

Comment: So `hthree_regions` ,`hthree_regions` and `titik_closurs` all seem to be pivot tables so you have (in practice) 2 entities being joined here (maybe with an implicit 3rd one?) so you can use either a nested relationship query (e.g. `Model::with('relationship1.relationship2')` and then aggregate all related models of `relationship2` within `relationship1` using e.g. a `flatMap` or you can try to make a many-to-many-through relationship (if that's possible, it might not be)

Comment: Please share your each tables columns if you can

Comment: I think you can do this with nested relation query with eloquent

Comment: @apokryfos so you mean something like this? `ZoneRegion::where()->with('areas', 'areas.hthree', 'areas.hthreee.segments', etc.)->get();` ?

Comment: @MohammadHosseini same question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

I was playing with codes and came up with union solution then it led me to `array_merge` which fixed my issue.

So what I did basically was getting all histories in separate variable and push it into my default array.

```
//get histories
$histories = DB::table('core_histories')->where('titik_id', $closure)->get();
// default function
$result = DB::table('zone_regions')......
//merge them into one
$res = array_merge($result, ['histories' => $histories]);
```

`Result`

```
data: {
  0: {...} // data
  histories: [ // histories
    0: {...}
    1: {...}
  ]
}
```

Hope it help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with nested relationship. If you have model for each table its easier for you. see below code:

ZoneRegion Model:

```
public function area() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Area::class); 
}
```

in Area model:

```
public function hthree() {
    return $this->belongsTo(HthreeRegions::class); 
}
```

and so on...

when you want to use and append array as you want you can do:

```
ZoneRegion::where('your condition')->with('area.hthree.segments.etc')->get();
```

Maybe my relationship is wrong because I don't know exactly what your relationship is like, and if you give an example or tell the relationship, maybe I can answer better.

But in the end, this method simply eliminates your need.

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

For this particular situation you seem to have 3 (or 4?) related models. It's far easier (and much more readable) to define them as relationships and then do a nested retrieval with aggregation say:

```
$zone = Zone::with('region.segment.link.titik')
   ->where('id', $request->input('zone');
$titik = $zone->region->flatMap(function ($region) { return $region->segment })
            ->flatMap(function ($segment) { return $segment->link })
            ->flatMap(function ($link) { return $segment->titik });
```

What could also work (with yout current approach):

```
$result = DB::table('zone_regions')
    ->where('zone_regions.id', '=', $request->input('zone'))
    ->join('areas', function ($join) use($area) {
        $join->on('zone_regions.id', '=', 'areas.zone_id')
        ->where('areas.id', '=', $area);
    })
    ->join('hthree_regions', function ($join) use($city) {
        $join->on('areas.id', '=', 'hthree_regions.area_id')
        ->where('hthree_regions.id', '=', $city);
    })
    ->join('segments', function ($join) use($segment) {
        $join->on('hthree_regions.id', '=', 'segments.hthree_id')
        ->where('segments.id', '=', $segment);
    })
    ->join('links', function ($join) use($link) {
        $join->on('segments.id', '=', 'links.segment_id')
        ->where('links.id', '=', $link);
    })
    ->join('titik_closurs', function ($join) use($closure) {
        $join->on('links.id', '=', 'titik_closurs.link_id')
        ->where('titik_closurs.id', '=', $closure);
    })
    // ->leftjoin('core_histories', 'titik_closurs.id', '=', 'core_histories.titik_id')
    // ->select('titik_closurs.*', 'core_histories.*')    
      ->get()
     ->groupBy('titik_closurs.id'); // Note the order change
```

This will use the collection's `groupBy` rather than the SQL `GROUP BY` (which does not provide any groups to the result)